# Convert string returned by new Date().toString() back to a date using date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Let's say I have produced a date like this:
`const myDate = new Date().toString()`

Using [JS date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), I now want to convert it back to a Date object so that I can use it in the other date-fns (e.g. `differenceInSeconds`).

How do I do that?

Comment: Why not simply assign new Date to a variable before converting to string lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date.parse()` to convert it to the milliseconds since the UNIX epoch or `new Date()` to convert it to a Date object. `date-fns` accepts both as arguments:

```
const differenceInSeconds = require('date-fns/differenceInSeconds');
const date1 = 'Thu Dec 17 2020 22:04:28 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)';
const date2 = 'Thu Dec 17 2020 22:13:34 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)';

differenceInSeconds(new Date(date2), new Date(date1));
// => 546

// OR
differenceInSeconds(new Date(date2), Date.parse(date1));
// => 546

// OR
differenceInSeconds(Date.parse(date2), Date.parse(date1));
// => 546
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use native JS like this?

```
Date.parse(myDate);
```